# NHibernate 2.0: What is the correct EntityMode: POCO, Map or Xml

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using some NHibernate 1.2 code with NHibernate 2.0 and its giving me an issue with this line:

```
return (TId) entityMeta.GetIdentifier(entity);
```

its asking me to add EntityMode: POCO, Map or Xml

```
return (TId) entityMeta.GetIdentifier(entity, EntityMode.Map);
```

But which mode is the correct one to use?

---

Here is the whole method:

```
public TId GetId<TId>(TEntity entity)
{
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionFactoryFor(assembly);

    if (sessionFactory == null)
    {
        sessionFactory = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionFactoryFor(GetNHibernateConfig());
    }

    IClassMetadata entityMeta = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(TEntity));

    return (TId) entityMeta.GetIdentifier(entity, EntityMode.Map);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  EntityMode.POCO, more info found on this [blog](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/16/less-than-gof-is-hbm.html)